# wysiwyg javascript editor replace images with text

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html, css, wysiwyg

I am currently working on a MVC4 asp.net project(my first, before I worked with WPF and winforms, no real website expierience). And I want to make a editor/wysiwyg for comments that people can make on items on the site. Everything is already setup but the comments are just written in a `<textarea/>`. Now I googled a bit and found a bunch of WYSIWYG editors for javascript, however I can t find a good one, or a good way to solve this issue:

Lets say the site is about poker (it is not but it is for easy example) and when a person makes a comment like "h9 is better then s10" once he posts (or at the time he types, that would even be better). The h9 is replaced by a hearts 9 jpg (or we can create a div of it and it has a `backgroundimage` css property)(all the jpgs are on the server ofc). (Same for the S10 it should be replaced by the spade 10 card image)

I got no clue how I can fix this, so any help with what wysiwyg editor I should use for this problem and how I could get closer to fixing it, would really be appreciated.

Maxim

Comment: Add the comment, and in the serverside code, replace all h9's with the divs you need. I wouldnt do this client side, although you can give an 'example' of how the comment is going to look (and doing the same in your example in JS).

Comment: With no "interference" by the user (eg, they're needing to add the markup vs. you just detect and wrap with additional markup)? If it's the former, you could hack Markup I suppose. I'd suggest the latter, and have a listener built into the editor to replace your key term/pairs with wrapped content on each `keyup` or whatnot.

Comment: CKEditor Developer Docs: [Data Processor: Data Input and Output Manipulation](http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Developers_Guide/Data_Processor)

Comment: Something you might consider is taking on a lower-orbit editor than TinyMCE and CKEditor (both awesome but wildly "complete") and instead target something like BB Code or Markdown (which SO uses), and then add your own "codes" to parse (maybe `[s9]`, `[s10]`, `[sj]`, etc. in BB Code), and then teach the users to use the stripped-down editor interface. If you don't need full-blowndedness (my own word there), and just want bold, italics and term displays, this would be a lot easier to manage.

Comment: could you give me a small example how to use BB code or markdown for this example? I am atm reading more about CKeditor I ll google it in a bit to check it out myself, sounds more interesting(since I am not realy that interseted in italic and all that stuff), but mayby I do want the quote tag too since ppl might want to quote / reply to each other

Comment: Take a look at [CL Editor](http://premiumsoftware.net/cleditor/), which has a demo showing how to insert icons and another for BB Code. You can download the source for each and see how they accomplished what they did with the configuration. This is probably your best avenue.

Comment: And here's a list to a whole bunch of editors: http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/category/goodies/wysiwyg-html-edit/

Comment: This is a recommendation question, explicitly disallowed I think...

Comment: partial mayby, but I mainly wanted to know how I could do this, and atm I am looking into bbcode and found http://bbcode.codeplex.com/ for the BBcode converting.

Comment: Here's a really light-weight BB Editor: http://corpocrat.com/2008/08/15/free-wysiwyg-bbcode-editor-in-javascript/ **EDIT**: That one looks promising.

Comment: And look at the smileys on the page here: http://markitup.jaysalvat.com/examples/bbcode/